# why do i always get a 404 on this function?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm using this function to check if a webpage exists. To do this I am checking if it has a header. But I always get a 404, even with a blank url.. what am I doing wrong here?

```
var xmlhttp;
function checkURL(url){
    xmlhttp=null; // initialize the request object
    // All the browsers except for the old IE
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=xmlhttpChange
        xmlhttp.open("HEAD",url,true)
        xmlhttp.send(null)
    }
    // old IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        if (xmlhttp)
        {
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=xmlhttpChange
            xmlhttp.open("HEAD",url,true)
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
}

function xmlhttpChange()
{
    // if loaded
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
        // if head exists "OK"
       if (xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
           alert('URL exists')
       }
       else
       {
           alert("Status is "+xmlhttp.status)
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works fine for any page that you are allowed to access.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/dPMah/

You can only access pages in the same domain using the XMLHTTP object.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the `url` variable will contain addresses to completely other sites, and is not just for checking internal paths in your application? You can't AJAX to another domain like that because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: but if this is not possible isnt there another way to check for headers in a url outside my domain?

Comment: as Guffa points out, your code does yield other values that 404's when not violating the same origin policy. There's not enough code in there to tell you why you don't get it to work within the same domain, but perhaps you're missing an initial slash, or something in your `url` variable. You should be able to see your within-same-domain request in your browser's development tools, and look at exactly what URL is being requested, and what the response is.

Comment: If you're using a server-side language as well, you could send an AJAX request to your own server, have the server submit a request to the remote URL, and return an indication of what the status code was.

Comment: my server doesnt alowserver php side includes and several other stuff, so im a bit limited on my options. thats why i was aiming for a clean javascript code to check if the site is online..

Comment: In php you can try `file_get_contents($url);`. There is no way to do this in javascript, for security reasons.